# SQL Pivot not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I am doing a pivot in SQL, but it's not working, can someone help what is wrong ? , below is my result set, desired output, and my query.

-->> The #Final temp table is created using below query.

```
CREATE TABLE #Final
    (
       Name VARCHAR(100),
       Code VARCHAR(20),
       Amount MONEY
    )

-->> Insert data, here i insert all data that i needed
INSERT INTO [#Final]
(
    [Name],
    [Code],
    [Amount]
)
SELECT something...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the result set

```
Name        Code    **Amount**
Batman      11111   4472.23
Batman      11111   -1788.89
Batman      22222   5166.98
Batman      22222   -5166.98
Batman      22222   5166.98
Batman      33333   6880.43
Batman      33333   -2293.47
Robin       11111   8278.54
Robin       11111   41392.66
Robin       22222   15940.95
Robin       22222   79704.71
Robin       33333   16557.23
Robin       33333   106136.1
Robin       33333   4669.99
Superman    11111   8944.39
Wolverine   11111   32782.99
Wolverine   11111   32782.99
Wolverine   11111   49671.2
Wolverine   11111   16557.06
Wolverine   22222   127527.54
Wolverine   33333   105074.74
Wolverine   33333   -420.3
-----------------------------------------------------------------

-->> My pivot query
SELECT [pvt].[Name], [1],[2],[3]
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, Code, Amount FROM #Final
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount) FOR Code IN ([1],[2],[3])
) pvt
```

The result of amount is all NULL

```
            11111   22222   33333
Batman      NULL    NULL    NULL
Robin       NULL    NULL    NULL
Superman    NULL    NULL    NULL
Wolverine   NULL    NULL    NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected result should be: (The sum of amount per Code per Name)

```
            11111       22222       33333
Batman      2683.34     5166.98     4586.96
Robin       49671.2     95645.66    127363.32
Superman    8944.39            0            0
Wolverine   131794.24   127527.54   104654.44
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column names should be:

```
[11111],[22222],[33333]
```

Instead of:

```
[1],[2],[3]
```

Here is your final query:

```
SELECT [pvt].[Name], [11111],[22222],[33333]
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, Code, Amount FROM #Final
) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount) FOR Code IN ([11111],[22222],[33333])
) pvt
```

Another way to get the desired result is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    [11111] = SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 11111 THEN Amount Else 0 END),
    [22222] = SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 22222 THEN Amount Else 0 END),
    [33333] = SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 33333 THEN Amount Else 0 END)
FROM #Final
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Sure, he can put `ISNULL` on the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Wow great! , now i see what is wrong .. this is my first time to create a pivot in SQL :) , i studied on how to create... i didn't observe that one.. this is perfect! , mark this as answer.

Comment: @Japongskie, that's why I prefer the conditional aggregation approach,

Comment: @FelixPamitstan , ahm can you show me on how can i achieve that using conditional aggregation ? , when i search in google.. the first thing i saw is that pivot.. how can i do that in conditional aggregation ?

Comment: @FelixPamittan , great! i tried the conditional aggregation, it works perfect too.. ahm i have a question, in terms of performance, what is the best to use ? , the pivot one , or the conditional agg ?

Comment: Based on [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/) by Jeff Moden, the conditional aggregation or crosstab has the advantage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98185/discussion-between-felix-pamittan-and-japongskie).

Comment: @FelixPamittan , Thanks , i'll take time to read that since this is my first time doing that pivot.. so much appreciated your help.. thanks :) Have a great day ahead. :)

Comment: @FelixPamittan , pilipino ka pala .. hahaha

Answer (score 1):

use `[11111],[22222],[33333]` instead of `[1],[2],[3]`